# What is the best way to format number variables with commas in javascript

Tags: javascript, numbers, number-formatting

I am running into an issue formatting a javascript number.  What is the equivalent of this csharp code in javascript:

```
 var cSharpNumber = 10000;
 string formattedNumber = cSharpNumber.ToString("#,###");  //this should show 10,000
```

I would like to avoid having to bring in other plugins if possible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't provide any way to do this out of the box, so you will have to use some custom code. A quick google search turned up this, which looks good to me:

http://www.mredkj.com/javascript/nfbasic.html

Answer (score 1):

I found that code a long time and it has been working fine since : http://phpjs.org/functions/number_format:481

Comment: The phpjs.org number_format is an excellent option. Here's a [jQuery wrapper](http://www.teamdf.com/web/jquery-number-format/178/) for that method.

Answer (score 0):

```
function addCommas(n){
    var rx=  /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
    return String(n).replace(/^\d+/, function(w){
        while(rx.test(w)){
            w= w.replace(rx, '$1,$2');
        }
        return w;
    });
}


returned values:
235=235
999.99=999.99
'1200000'=1,200,000
12345=12,345
10652.23=10,652.23
```